# match one column of one table to data of other table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, join

I have 2 tables - table1 and table2. table1 is a follows:

```
ID
A01
A02
A03
A04
A05
```

table2 is a follows:

```
DeptID  Name        ID
5       groupA      A01
5       groupA      A03
5       groupA      A04
5       groupB      A02
5       groupB      A04
5       groupB      A05
```

table3:

```
Codename    DisplayName
groupA      Humti
groupB      Dumpti
```

I want to the output as:

```
DeptID  Name         ID    Result
5       Humpti       A01   1
5       Humpti       A02   0
5       Humpti       A03   1
5       Humpti       A04   1
5       Humpti       A05   0
5       Dumpti       A01   0
5       Dumpti       A02   1
5       Dumpti       A03   0
5       Dumpti       A04   1
5       Dumpti       A05   1
```

Here, groupA has 3 IDs attached to it. A01, A03, A04. So for these the Result Column in the output has value 1. But for A02, A05 groupA is not associated, so Result column value is 0. Only thing we need to remember is groupA will be compared with all the IDs of table1.

**Edit** : All solutions worked pretty great, but can I replace the 'groupA' with 'Humpti' and 'groupB' with 'Dumpti' based on the values found in the table3??

Thanks..

Comment: How can you match the `name` column which has values of `GroupA, GroupB` to the `ID` column which has a values of `A01,A02`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t2.deptId, t2.name, table1.id, CASE WHEN table2.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END result
FROM table1, (SELECT distinct deptId, group from table2) t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON t2.name = table2.name AND t2.ID = table1.ID
```

EDIT, for your changed problem:

```
SELECT t2.deptId, table3.name, table1.id, CASE WHEN table2.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END result
FROM table1, table3, (SELECT distinct deptId, name from table2) t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON t2.name = table2.name AND t2.ID = table1.ID
WHERE table3.codename = t2.name
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will return the data set you want. The requirements are a little odd though, so it may not work when you extend to do other things:

```
select 
    sub.*,
    result = case when t.ID is null then 0 else 1 end
from 
    (
    select distinct
        t2.DeptID,
        t2.Name,
        t1.ID
    from
        table1 t1,
        table2 t2
) sub
left join table2 t on sub.ID = t.ID and sub.name = t.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ddn.DeptID
     , ddn.Name
     , did.ID
     , CASE WHEN t2.id IS NOT NULL 
              THEN 1 
              ELSE 0 
       END AS Result
FROM 
     table1 AS did
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT DISTINCT 
          DeptID
        , Name
      FROM table2
    ) AS ddn
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 
    ON  t2.ID = did.ID
    AND t2.DeptID = ddn.DeptID
    AND t2.Name = ddn.Name
```